# Specific imports of typescript enums cannot be loaded

Tags: typescript, npm, enums, npm-publish

I published a typescript package to NPM and use it in the context of a few other typescript apps, mainly for reusing some common enum values. the common package builds and works well for some types of imports but not for others. for example, this code will run correctly

```
import * as common from 'my-common';
const myEnum: common.enums.MY_ENUM = common.enums.MY_ENUM.ENUM1;
if (myEnum === common.enums.MY_ENUM.ENUM1) {
  console.log('ok');
}
```

whereas the following builds fine but throws an error on run time

```
import { MY_ENUM } from 'my-common/dist/types/enums';
const myEnum: MY_ENUM = MY_ENUM.ENUM1;
if (myEnum === MY_ENUM.ENUM1) {
  console.log('ok');
}

Error:
[1] Provided module can't be loaded.
[1] Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
[1] Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'my-common/dist/types/enums'
```

I would expect the specific import of 'my-common/dist/types/enums' to work, but it doesn't. the common typescript file (describer-common/dist/types/enums.ts) is:

```
export declare enum MY_ENUM {
  ENUM1 = "enum1",
  ENUM2 = "enum2",
  ENUM3 = "enum3",
}
```

Content of package tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your package tsconfig.json?

Comment: @ClusterH, yes updated it in the post.

Comment: I think you have no index.ts file to point your enums with subfolder link when you import in your apps. only you are exporting enums in root level index file. To solve this, you need to make `/types/enums` folder and make index.ts file inside of them, and export your enum. For the custom importing (For example, `import { MY_ENUM } from 'your_package/types/enums'`, etc, you need to adjust package.json file exports section ). Kindly share your source what you are doing. It would be better to correct answer.
I prefer you to share your package source git link, so I can check more deeply.

Comment: My version is in a private repo right now but I was basing it on https://github.com/tomchen/example-typescript-package. simply created src/Enums.ts and added it to src/index.ts in the same way that Num.ts is added in here. the only difference that Enums exports a bunch of enums instead of a class.

Comment: are you aware of simplistic public TS package repo that does this type of enum exports? maybe best if I use that as a reference.

Comment: @kob490 Did you make any progress with this issue or find a workaround? I am seeing the same for enum imports.